# Some bash commands in VIM send output to bash instead of VIM

Tags: linux, bash, vim

Whenever I type the following in the vim command line: `:read !readlink {somedir}`
,it sends output to the bash I started vim from, not to the vim buffer.
Actually, What I am trying achieve is to get the absolute path of files while editing a file with vim, and not to make any typos in it.

On the other hand, whenever I use for example: `:read !ls`, it prints the output in the vim buffer I am currently using.

Why is this happening and what should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want yo find the complete path of the current file (not the relative path given by `:! echo "%"`), and include that in your file (as a kind of header, and would you like something like the current date in the header too) ? Or do you want to look up all kind of files? Can you use `locate` for this?

Comment: I want to get the full path of all kind of files or directories. It's because sometimes when I'm configuring something I have to give the absolute path to files or dirs and there is a good chance that I make mistake when typing the path or eg. miss a dir in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the absolute path use:

```
:read ! realpath directory-name
```

Comment: Along the way I realized that I used readlink incorrectly. If I use it correctly It also prints the output (in this case, the absolute path of something) inside vim as in that case stdout is used. In case of error, It uses stderr, but stder isn't "channeled" into the current vim buffer, but to the bash you started vim from.

Comment: When it works accept the answer ! the minimum you can do !

Comment: Sorry, it was my very first question in stackoverflow. It slipped my mind.

Answer (score 0):

When stderr is giving problems, you can use `2>&1`.
The commandline will become boring long with all req's. When you need this often, take another approach.
First make a script that will give the correct path as output fulfilling your requirements.
The script can use find, locate, readlink or some AI resolving errors in the path. After that you can use

```
:r !myscript path
```

And when you use this real often, assign it to a function key like

```
nnoremap <F1> :r !myscript 

"Off topic: I like the next one for testing scripts
nnoremap <F9> :w<Enter>:!%:p<Enter>
```